# calculating the necessary number of randomly chosen numbers less than N, so that they contain n B-smooth numbers

Tags: probability, number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-factorization

I am reading about smooth numbers to find the time-complexity of the quadratic sieve (as a side topic on a cryptography book), and the author makes the following claim:

The probability that a randomly chosen number modulo $N$ is $B$-smooth is $\frac{\psi(N,B)}{N}$. In order to find $\pi(B)$ numbers that are B-smooth, we need to check approximately:

                                                                                       $\frac{\pi(B)}{\psi(N,B)/N}$ numbers

where $\pi(B)$ is the number of primes less than or equal to $B$, $\psi(N,B)$ is the number of $B$-smooth numbers less than $N$.

The question is I don't know how the author got to this approximate value.

Comment: "B-smooth number" is a concept that you surely master, but this is not the case for most people here... A reference is mandatory.

Comment: @JeanMarie I thought that "B-smooth numbers" is a basic number theory concept. anyway, the details of "smooth numbers" here aren't important: just consider them as a subset of the numbers less than N, whose cardinality is given by the psi function in the question. The question is mainly a probability question.

Comment: In any case, the claim seems incomplete. In what sense do they mean "approximately"? Usually we would give an associated probability with the event of interest.

Comment: @dmh Exactly, but being a cryptography book (not purely math), the author doesn't give all details. So, I am hoping someone could catch what he did.

Comment: I gave an answer, it sounds like they are interested in the expectation. I wonder how they are using this result.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the author is computing the expectation of the number of times before $m$ B-smooth numbers are found. Let $T_i$ be the number of samples we draw between the $i-1^{th}$ success and the $i^{th}$ success. Then we are interested in:

$$\mathbb E [\sum_i^m T_i] = \sum_i^m \mathbb E [T_i] = m * 1/p$$

where the first equality follows by linearity of expectation, and the second comes from the fact that $T_i$ each follows a geometric distribution with parameter $p$.

In your problem, $m$ is $\pi(B)$ and $p$ is $\psi(B, N)/N$

Comment: Wouldn't every success or failure influence the parameter p, because either the sample space, the number of B-smooth numbers left, or both will change with each step

Comment: For sure, i would expect this to actually be more similar to the coupon collector problem. In my answer I tried to guess the assumptions the author made.

Comment: If we didn't eliminate every failure number, it is less efficient but theoretically ok, so every E(T_i) will be 1/p_i. but all successes must be eliminated from the sample space and the available smooth numbers to avoid repetition. So, p_i must decrease after each success.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see the your comment. Thanks anyway, this was really helpful